# Display Video In Header Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have an API to display video (mp4/swf). I need to use return video in header in raw format instead of return `<video>`.

**EDIT** In laravel:

```
$response = Response::make($videolink, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
return $response;
```

Actual output: download video instead of display video.

Comment: @jogo added. please advice.

Comment: I think that  behaviour download/play is actually dependant on the browser of the user.

Comment: @Amarnasan so how should I do to display video in header?

Comment: `display video in header` is little confusing. can you explain a little on this